# Unable to view DOC(X) in Emacs: "Unable to render file"

Tags: emacs, ms-office, doc

I am unable to view any DOCX or DOC documents on Emacs.
I get the error: `Unable to render file`

My pdftotext-executable is set to pdftotext.

Comment: DOC(X) is not the same as PDF.

Comment: How to see DOCX or DOC files? When I M-x doc-view-mode it says "Unable to render file. View extracted tex instead (y or n).